# {% for x in user.userprofile.xs.all() %} Template error

Tags: python, django

I was trying to write `{% for x in user.userprofile.xs.all() %}` in a django template but its throwing a Template error. Here `x` is a `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: You should  post the error & the code ...

Comment: Remove the (), they're added by the template machinery

Comment: Not exactly true that `()` is added, but a method call is one of the ways the template engine will resolve dot notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
{% for x in user.userprofile.xs.all %}
```

in template you do `.all` and you do in views `.all()`